# Typing a string index

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, indexing

I have some data.

```
const people = {
    john : {
     //somedata
    },
   peter : {
     //somedata
    },
   mark: {
     //somedata
    }
}
```

and I type it

```
  export type People = {
     [key : string]: Person
   }


 export interface Person {
   age: number;
   profession: string;
 // some more data

   }
```

The error is **TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type**. I would not usually use a string as the key but in this case it is necessary and typescript does not like it even though I have told it to expect a string.

Any idea how I can type this properly?

Comment: Are you sure Its because of type? I tried like this its fine.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUxHANgmBeGBvAUDAmAKxAAswYAuHfQmAenohAFsEATAQyk9oIF8ANH0RQEAJyo06DJqw7dedIXxadxAa2p4ZjZmy48+MfrlNQAnohgAFJKnRYddANoaEFqdHEBLMAHMAXWo7cWYwM1wovzFxADNOYHRQ8OkCTn8EajAAVxYAIwkAbhFxEDiECAgfcGpvP38SvlNcUEhYEBD7NEwcACJOCHY+7QysgEYABkF4MoqqmrBqAHIxaAbl-n4StuY0ADoUEH8AChAASiA

Comment: will try again thanks.

Comment: Where does that error occur? Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/W4884W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.